# A strictly decreasing function between uncountable subsets of the reals

Tags: set-theory, real-analysis, order-theory, linear-orders

By a standard technique of inductive killing everything relevant (in this case decreasing homeomorphisms between uncountable $G_\delta$-subsets of the real line) it is possible to prove the following fact.

> **Theorem (CH).** Under CH the real line contains an uncountable subset $X$ admitting no strictly decreasing function $f:Z\to X$, defined on some uncountable subset $Z$ of $X$.

On the other hand, a known PFA-results of Baumgartner (about the order isomorphness of any $\aleph_1$-dense subsets of the real line) implies the following

> **Theorem (PFA).** Under PFA, for any uncountable subset $X\subset\mathbb R$ there exists a strictly decreasing function $f:Z\to X$, defined on some uncountable subset $Z\subset X$.

Now

> **Question.** Can this PFA-theorem be proved under a weaker assumption like OCA or (MA$+\neg$ CH)?

Comment: "defined on an": do you mean "defined on any"? the article "a" is ambiguous, especially in such sentences.

Comment: @YCor Thank you for the comment. I changed "an" to "some".

Comment: OK now the meaning is clear. Anyway the correct English is "any", since the sentence is in the negative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Todorcevic's book ["Partition Problems in Topology"](https://books.google.com.ua/books/about/Partition_Problems_in_Topology.html?id=k6UZnZ_qkgIC&redir_esc=y) I have found Proposition 8.4(c) saying that under OCA for any uncountable sets $X,Y$ of reals there exists a strictly increasing function $f:Z\to Y$ defined on some uncountable subset $Z$ of $X$.

This proposition implies that for any uncountable set $X\subset \mathbb R$ there exists a strictly increasing function $f:Z\to -X$ defined on some uncountable subset $Z\subset X$. Then the function $-f:Z\to X$ is stricly decreasing.

> Therefore the PFA-theorem in OP holds under OCA.

Comment: To complement this answer, I think the answer should be no for $\mathsf{MA}$. Abraham and Shelah proved that $\mathsf{MA}$ doesn't give you Baumgartner's theorem by showing $\mathsf{MA}$ is consistent with the existence of something called an *entangled set* of reals. I think an entangled set shouldn't admit the sort of map you're describing. (I don't have time to check the details today, which is why I'm just writing a comment -- I hope this helps.)

Comment: @WillBrian Thank you for the comment. I will try to check the paper of Abraham-Shelah.